# Full screen menu working just on first slide of slider not on the rest - CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I am using swiper slider for my website and I encountered an issue with adding full-screen menu on each slide.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});


$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Swiper */

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }




/* Menu */

.container.menu a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF5252;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .35s ease;
}

.container.menu a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.button_container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container span {
  background: #FF5252;
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, width .35s;
  z-index: 50;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  left: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left .35s ease;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  right: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay.open:before {
  left: 0;
}

.overlay.open:after {
  right: 0;
}

.overlay.open li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .55s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .65s;
}

.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover:after,
.overlay ul li a:focus:after,
.overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.75rem !important;
  }
  nav li {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  nav li a:hover {
    color: black;
  }
  nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 3
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

A hamburger menu button is displayed only on the first slide even though is added on all of them.

When I click on it it won't open. When I use this menu outside of slide it works just fine.

Not sure what am I missing any tip appreciated!

Comment: Why have a the same menu repeated three times ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Because I need navigation on my each slide. Every slide represents separate page on website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `overlay <div>`s outside the swiper with different ids each.

```
  <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
  </div>
 <div class="overlay" id="overlay0">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay1">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> 
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay2">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eleven </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twelve</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

so, `swiper-container` div remains like this

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            Slide 1
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            Slide 2
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            Slide 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

then, change the `#toggle` click function as follow

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay' + swiper.activeIndex).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer for the comment "Have just one more question if I don't want to display button just on first slide what should I do?"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  //////////// added
  on: {
    slideChange: function(){
        if(this.activeIndex == 0) $("#toggle").hide();
        else $("#toggle").show();
    }
  } //////////// added


});

$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay'+swiper.activeIndex).toggleClass('open');
});

$("#toggle").hide();  //////////// added
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your code and hamburger button is displayed but I can't still click on it

Comment: did you change `id="overlay0"`, `id="overlay1"` and `id="overlay2"`? and `$('#overlay' + swiper.activeIndex).toggleClass('open');`?

Comment: Yes sir, hamburger button is displayed correctly but when open it doesn't have proper css style on it like class overlay is not showing

Comment: It's working just as I wanted :) Thank you very much for your time and effort! It was my bad.. it was messing with other jQuery code I had...

Comment: Have just one more question if I don't want to display button just on first slide what should I do?

Comment: firstly add `$("#toggle").hide();` 
secondly add `on: {
 slideChange: function(){
  if(this.activeIndex == 0) $("#toggle").hide();
  else $("#toggle").show();
 }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Your menus have `position:fixed`, which positions them relative to their closest viewport. Normally, that's the `<body>`, but there are CSS properties which can cause an element to act as viewport for its children.

One such property is `transform` with any 3d transformation effect. Which is what's applied to your slider container. In this case, the slider container acts as a viewport to the menus, which all overlap.

A bad fix would be to apply a 3d inert transformation to each slide: `transform: rotatez(0)`. Example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});


$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Swiper */

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Menu */

.container.menu a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF5252;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .35s ease;
}

.container.menu a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.button_container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container span {
  background: #FF5252;
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, width .35s;
  z-index: 50;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  left: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left .35s ease;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  right: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay.open:before {
  left: 0;
}

.overlay.open:after {
  right: 0;
}

.overlay.open li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .55s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .65s;
}

.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover:after,
.overlay ul li a:focus:after,
.overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
.swiper-slide {transform: rotatez(0)}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 3
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Note you currently have duplicate ids which will make your jQuery behave unexpectedly, but that's a different issue, outside of the scope of this question. If you need help with that problem, post a different question about it.

---

**The proper solution** is to have one single menu placed outside of the slider. It will be displayed over your slider, hence over each slide. Unless your menus are different and specific to each particular slide, appending the site menu to each slide is something you want to avoid.

Good fix example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});

$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('.toggle').removeClass('active');
  if (!$(this).closest('.overlay').is('div')) {
    $('.toggle', $('#overlay')).addClass('active');
  }
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Swiper */

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Menu */

.container.menu a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF5252;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .35s ease;
}

.container.menu a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.button_container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}
.button_container.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container span {
  background: #FF5252;
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, width .35s;
  z-index: 50;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  left: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left .35s ease;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  right: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay.open:before {
  left: 0;
}

.overlay.open:after {
  right: 0;
}

.overlay.open li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .55s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .65s;
}

.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover:after,
.overlay ul li a:focus:after,
.overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
.swiper-slide {
  transform: rotatez(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <div class="button_container toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
      <div class="button_container toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 3
      <div class="button_container toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

If you have specific menus for each slide, go with the "bad" fix, but make sure you fix your ids and jQuery to account for each button opening its respective menu.

Comment: Well as you say bad fix would be something that I need because I won't be displaying menu on first slide so I definitely have to have different id's.. But then just to check how different would jQuery act.

Comment: That's not enough reason to place the menu inside each slide. Place only a toggle inside the slides and make one menu, toggleable by any of the toggles, outside of the slide. I'll update the second example to match your requirement.

Comment: Updated example 2 with what you described.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code here**

I am changing little code the hamburger button id to class because of the swiper slider regenerate your HTML on his won formate, so I changed the code document click.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
$(document).on('click','.toggle',function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Swiper */

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Menu */

.container.menu a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF5252;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .35s ease;
}

.container.menu a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.button_container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(10px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container span {
  background: #FF5252;
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, width .35s;
  z-index: 50;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  left: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left .35s ease;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FF5252;
  right: -55%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay.open:before {
  left: 0;
}

.overlay.open:after {
  right: 0;
}

.overlay.open li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .55s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .65s;
}

.overlay nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover:after,
.overlay ul li a:focus:after,
.overlay ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
      <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 3
      <div class="button_container toggle" onClick="getMe">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <nav class="overlay-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

**=== Thank you ===**

Comment: Hamburger button is displayed only on first slide. I want it displayed on second and third and not on first.

Comment: What is the problem if you keep the button and overlay outer site from the slider?

Comment: NO there is not problem with that, that is the solution but from your code and mine also the hamburger button was just on first slide. But I want button on secon and third slide and not on first :)